# ObjectSet.ApplyCurrentValues v/s StateManager.ChangeObjectState

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, poco

I am quite new to Entity Framework 4.1. I am starting to write a new application using EF as my DAL. I am using POCO classes (using POCO t4 template) with database first approach.

My GenericRepository has got below Update method

```
public void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
    }

    _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
    //_objectSet.ApplyCurrentValues(entity);
}
```

I having a gridview which is databind to ObjectDataSource having UpdateMethod="UpdateStore" which takes only one parameter is as follows...

```
public void UpdateStore(Store franchise)
{
    unitOfWork.StoreRepository.Attach(franchise);
    unitOfWork.StoreRepository.Update(franchise);
    unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}
```

I got couple of question here:

1. When I see the documentation for [ApplyCurrentValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx), it proves me that I should use this to update values but this doesn't work (as you can see in above commented line). Then when I try with ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState, it works. What's the difference between this two approaches.
2. As you can see, I attach first and then apply the update method. Can I combine attach and updating state inside my GenericRepository update method. Is there any pitfall there in doing so?

Comment: I got quite a bit of understanding on that using the link I edited for ApplyCurrentValues. So it has to a extent solved first question, but would love to know about 2nd question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `ApplyCurrentChanges` is used when you have attached entity loaded from the database and you want to update its values from detached entity received from your `ObjectDataSource`. When you do this all new values are copied to attached entity and it is automatically marked as `Modified`. `ChangeObjectState` is used to change state of attached entity - it does nothing else. Calling `Attach` attaches entity in `Unchanged` state so it is the reason why you must change the state to get your changes persisted in the database..
2. Yes you can combine attaching and setting state in the single method. Just need to make sure that you will call this method only once for each entity. Attaching entity with the same `Id` twice will throw exception.